# Haskell: simplehttp appending "%0D"?

Tags: string, haskell, http-conduit

I am using simplehttp to query webpage. eg: let webLink = "www.example.com/" and number= 257 (number is read from file).

```
res <- simpleHttp $ "webLink" ++ number
```

It  is working fine on windows but on mac, it is throwing error 404 as its showing path as "www.example.com/257%0D"
I have no idea where this "%0D" is coming from because printing number is giving me 257 . I have tried filtering "%0D" as well like below, but still mac is showing error 404 due to %0D in path...Please suggest.

```
res <- simpleHttp $ (filter (not . (`elem` "%0D")) ("webLink" ++ number))
```

Comment: That should probably be `%0D` (with a zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0x0D` character is a component of the newline sequence on windows but not on mac. You are probably reading in a line from your windows-encoded file that contains a windows newline that your mac doesn't understand without a little help from you.